# Configure php 5.3 fail with error : freetype.h not found (but libfreetype6-dev is installed)

Tags: php, compiler-errors

I have configured php with the following command:

```
./configure \
--prefix=/opt/phpfcgi-5.3.28 \
--with-pdo-pgsql \
--with-zlib-dir \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2 \
--with-libpng-dir=/usr/include/libpng \
--with-xpm-dir=/usr \
--enable-mbstring \ls \
--with-libxml-dir=/usr \
--enable-soap \
--enable-calendar \
--with-curl \
--with-mcrypt \
--with-zlib \
--with-gd \
--with-pgsql \
--disable-rpath \
--enable-inline-optimization \
--with-bz2 \
--with-zlib \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-sysvsem \
--enable-sysvshm \
--enable-pcntl \
--enable-mbregex \
--with-mhash \
--enable-zip \
--with-pcre-regex \
--with-mysql \
--with-mysql-dir=/etc/mysql/ \
--with-pdo-mysql \
--with-mysqli \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
--with-png-dir=/usr \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--with-openssl \
--with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
--enable-ftp \
--with-kerberos \
--with-gettext \
--enable-cgi \
--with-fpm-user=www-data \
--with-fpm-group=www-data
```

But if I try to compile, I got the Error-Message:

> configure: error: freetype.h not found

Comment: also see bug reports https://bugs.php.net/66259 and https://bugs.php.net/64405

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you got that message, even if you installed **libfreetype6-dev**, then try this:

```
mkdir /usr/include/freetype2/freetype
ln -s /usr/include/freetype2/freetype.h /usr/include/freetype2/freetype/freetype.h
```

After this, do .configure again.

Additional hint: For some Systems you have to use /usr/**local**/include....

Comment: This worked for me when compiling PHP 5.1 on Debian Jessie. Mission impossible for a legacy project. Thanks.

Comment: On Alpine Linux it's `freetype-dev`